# Maps API Fragment not showing Marker in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, maps, google-maps-markers

I'm new with StackOverflow and Maps API. I'm developing an app where a Drawer Layout is being used. I want to use one of the Drawer fragments to show Maps and work with Markers.

```
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)   
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
     mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

this is the fragment_maps.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.labcontrol.lca.view.MapsFragment">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.labcontrol.lca.controller.MainActivity" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In the official guide they made an example using an Activity, as you can see I tried to do it inside a fragment. is it possible?

The result is this: maps is working properly, but I can't see the Marker I created, and I spent too many hours trying to figure out why.
The only thing make me suspicious is this error when playing with Maps on the phone and changing the camera:

W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op

Found out it's a common issue these days, a very new bug. Somebody knows how to get it up and running? Is there something wrong with the code? 
thanks a lot

Comment: how come you are looking for the map fragment before inflating fragment_maps?

Comment: It was in onCreateView at the beginning indeed, but it didn't work, so I tried putting the inflate in onCreate and other changes. Tried everything, also double checked the Manifest, xml, and replaced the API key ..I wonder if is it actually possible to put the fragment Map inside a fragment!